# Android app icon gets displayed as the default Android icon instead of the one in my drawable folder

Tags: android, android-drawable

I had set all my ic_launcher.png files in the drawable folders of my app. And almost in every occasion, the app icon gets displayed properly. But when it is displayed on my device, only the green Android default icon shows up.

Would anyone know how to debug this situation or why this happens? My device is the HTC One which is a VERY big phone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Also, try to run the project once after changing your assets so that a new APK file would be generated. Transfer this APK File to your phone.

Comment: @Nisha :) I did all the clean/new apk kind of things...trying again just in case.

Comment: In all drawable folders, is the new file available, that too in the same name ic_launcher.png?

Comment: @Genadinik try to uninstall the app and re-install it again maybe because your divice caches already the green android icon.

Comment: @Nisha yes, it is named that everywhere :)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin actually you were right :))))) if you'd like add that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Added an answer which is a more hands down approach to solving this problem.

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia Thank you so much! I've been banging my head for almost 3 hours now trying to fix it. Cleaning the project worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uninstall the app and re-install it again maybe because your device caches already the green android icon within it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you place your custom icon in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder too?

Android uses the file from the resources that match the device's characteristics as closely as possible. The HTC One has a 468 ppi display, so it would fall into the xxhpdi bucket.

Just a theory, but you might have replaced all the other versions of the icon, and the default icon that Eclipse/Android Studio create by default might be there still.

Comment: @mitiash yes I replaced the original icon. I guess the current green icon I am seeing is an Android default?

Comment: yeah I was looking at the xxhdpi, but it is all normal as well.

Comment: Sorry. It was worth a shot. I've made this mistake before.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the right image is available in all relevant folders
2. Clean project in eclipse. (If required, restart eclipse)
3. Run in emulator, so new APK is generated.
4. Uninstall the existing APK in your mobile phone.
5. Install the new APK in your mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered but, for those still looking for a solution try this:

make a copy of your apk file and rename it to myapp.zip i.e. change extension from apk to zip (where myapp is the name of your apk file). Extract the zip and take a look inside the res folder which will be in the extracted folder. Verify if the image you are intending to have as your icon is actually there. From there you can either place your icon there and remove the default icon (DO NOT CHANGE the NAME) or manually debug from eclipse or whatever ide your are using. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got this problem solved - change user to guest and back. nothing else worked for me (even cleaning launcher cash and reloading phone) . Hope i helped someone good luck

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue by a silly copy/paste mistake. I added the multidex-line into the AndroidManifest.xml and didn't recognice the '>' at the end.

```
    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

So the application section ends after the first line, resulting in the default icon. Also the app name (label) wasn't taken. Instead the package name was used.
This is the corrected version:

```
    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your `build.gradle`.

My issue was that I had `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in my `build.gradle` under defaultConfig because I was using an `ImageButton` and setting the source with `android:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that another Manifest in the project was also trying to load a launcher icon which was overwriting the icon I set in the app manifest. Check all manifests and make sure only one icon is being set.